# Re-install Azure AD Connect fails

Tags: active-directory, azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id, azureadconnect

Previously installed AAD Connect and synced from local AD domain to Azure AD (Office 365). Had catastrophic on-premise failure and rebuilt domain from scratch. Now trying to re-install AAD Connect and establish sync from "new" domain to Office 365 tenant. Already broke previous sync on O365 and waited 72+ hours before retrying install. Now, keep getting the below 2 errors; no proxy involved, one server directly connected to ISP modem, verified specific O365 network connectivity via 3rd party script. Any help greatly appreciated.

---

> [12:07:08.475] [ 46] [INFO ] Configuring Windows Azure Active Directory Sync: Updating run profiles and attribute inclusion lists for connector (companyname.onmicrosoft.com - AAD)
>   Exception Data (Raw): System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: token ---> Microsoft.IdentityManagement.PowerShell.ObjectModel.SynchronizationConfigurationValidationException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: token
>      at Microsoft.DirectoryServices.MetadirectoryServices.UI.WebServices.MMSWebService.ValidateConfigurationParameters(Connector connector)
>      at Microsoft.DirectoryServices.MetadirectoryServices.UI.WebServices.MMSWebService.CreateConnector(Connector connector, Boolean validate)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityManagement.PowerShell.Cmdlet.AddADSyncConnectorCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
>      at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
>      at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
>      at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
>      at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
>      at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
>      at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.LocalPowerShell.Invoke()
>      at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.PowerShellAdapter.TypeDependencies.InvokePowerShell(IPowerShell powerShell)
>      at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.PowerShellAdapter.InvokePowerShellCommand(String commandName, InitialSessionState initialSessionState, IDictionary`2 commandParameters, Boolean isScript)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.PowerShellConfigAdapter.ConnectorConfigAdapter.AddConnector(Connector connector)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Config.ConnectorAdapterBase.CreateOrUpdateConnectorCore()
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.ActionExecutor.Execute(Action action, String description)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Config.ConnectorAdapterBase.CreateOrUpdateConnector(IEnumerable`1 objectClassInclusions, IEnumerable`1 attributeNameInclusions, ParameterKeyedCollection connectorGlobalParameters, Boolean createRunProfile)
>      at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.Types.Providers.SyncDataProvider.CreateConnectorWithRetry(ConnectorAdapterBase connectorAdapter, IEnumerable`1 objectClassInclusions, IEnumerable`1 attributeNameInclusions, ParameterKeyedCollection connectorGlobalParameters, Boolean createRunProfile)

---

> [12:07:11.789] [ 46] [ERROR] Creation of connector companyname.onmicrosoft.com - AAD failed. This may be due to replication delay. Retrying after 5 seconds ...
>   Exception Data (Raw): System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: token ---> Microsoft.IdentityManagement.PowerShell.ObjectModel.SynchronizationConfigurationValidationException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: token
>      at Microsoft.DirectoryServices.MetadirectoryServices.UI.WebServices.MMSWebService.ValidateConfigurationParameters(Connector connector)
>      at Microsoft.DirectoryServices.MetadirectoryServices.UI.WebServices.MMSWebService.CreateConnector(Connector connector, Boolean validate)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityManagement.PowerShell.Cmdlet.AddADSyncConnectorCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
>      at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
>      at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
>      at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
>      at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
>      at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
>      at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.LocalPowerShell.Invoke()
>      at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.PowerShellAdapter.TypeDependencies.InvokePowerShell(IPowerShell powerShell)
>      at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.PowerShellAdapter.InvokePowerShellCommand(String commandName, InitialSessionState initialSessionState, IDictionary`2 commandParameters, Boolean isScript)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.PowerShellConfigAdapter.ConnectorConfigAdapter.AddConnector(Connector connector)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Config.ConnectorAdapterBase.CreateOrUpdateConnectorCore()
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Framework.ActionExecutor.Execute(Action action, String description)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.Config.ConnectorAdapterBase.CreateOrUpdateConnector(IEnumerable`1 objectClassInclusions, IEnumerable`1 attributeNameInclusions, ParameterKeyedCollection connectorGlobalParameters, Boolean createRunProfile)
>      at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.Types.Providers.SyncDataProvider.CreateConnectorWithRetry(ConnectorAdapterBase connectorAdapter, IEnumerable`1 objectClassInclusions, IEnumerable`1 attributeNameInclusions, ParameterKeyedCollection connectorGlobalParameters, Boolean createRunProfile)

---

Comment: I would suggest opening a support ticket for this, our support team will be in a much better position to assist on this.